# Fenders for Marin Four Corners 2020

Tags: fenders

I bought a Marin Four Corners bike and I have a problem with choosing fenders. I found information in the web that SKS Velo 65 fenders fit there, but during installation it turned out that they do not fit there (they are too wide). Marin changed something in the width of the frame over the rear wheel? Now I don't really know what to put there. Maybe someone from the community will advise or recommend something?

P.S. I would prefer something shorter at the back because I am transporting a bike in an elevator on the rear wheel.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the SKS Velo 55? it's 10mm narrower. There is also a 47mm version which might only just fit around your 42mm tyres. You could also cut or file away the offending portion of your existing mudguards to make them fit.

Comment: Show where the 65s you have are too wide and how bad it is. Shaving them or letting them be a little squished is sometimes the best option.

Comment: I added a new photo to show the amount of free space